# Manually trigger a revision for select query in Envers

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

I am auditing a Java object using Hibernate Envers annotations. Now I want to add audit for select query basically for read operation. Is it possible? Or can I maually insert the data into Audit table for the read operation
?

I have tried to write CustomeRevisionListner and maually trigger a revision, but did not get the result.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.